# Connexion class based handling

Tags: python, flask, connexion

I'm using the [connexion](http://connexion.readthedocs.io) framework for flask. I'd like to group several related functions into a class and I'm wondering whether methods of a class can be used for operationId instead of functions.

Something like

```
class Job:

    def get():
        "something"

    def post():
        "something"
```

in the describing `yaml` file:

```
 paths:
    /hello:
        post:
            operationId: myapp.api.Job.post
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: It's quite clear.

Comment: In connexion operation id are mapped to functions which handles requests.
Can we do it using functions in classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the methods if they are available as staticmethods on the class:

```
class Job:

    @staticmethod
    def get():
        "something"

    @staticmethod
    def post():
        "something"
```